# Is there a shortcut to write a function with the same definition but different prototypes?

Tags: c++, function, class, definition

I have a method of a class which basically looks like this:

```
void MyClass::method() {
    // Here I'm just doing something with parameters which are class attributes
    parameter_3 = parameter_1 + parameter_2
}
```

I need another method which would have exactly the same body, but now I want the parameters to be passed in with the function call:

```
void MyClass::method(type1_t parameter_1, type2_t parameter_2);
```

I do not want to repeat the same code in another definition. What are possible solutions? The less ugly the better.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. The first method is assigning values to class members. The second method is taking in values as input. So, these two methods would likely not want to have the exact same body, as assigning new values to parameters doesn't usually make sense to do unless they are output parameters. So, can you please provide a better example of what you are really trying to accomplish? Typically, if you need two (or more) methods to share the same logic, you simply have one call the other.

Comment: @RemyLebeau not a good example, do not pay too much attention to the body of the function, the thing is I use parameters that are attributes in the first case and passed in parameters in the second one. It is not about how I use them, it is about the point that the code in the function definition is exactly the same

Comment: Have you tried passing the parameters by reference?  In your first method, the variables are assigned values.

Comment: Constructor boilerplate is often something that cannot be condensed.

Comment: Just have the no-args overload call the with-args overload to do the common work?

Comment: @MilesBudnek how am I supposed to pass in parameters to with-args overload via no-args overload?

Comment: @Kaiyakha `void MyClass::method() { method(default_value_1, default_value_2); }`?

Comment: @Human-Compiler If `default_value` is an attribute, well then that's an option, although a bit ugly. Anyway, thanks, will try this one

Comment: @Kaiyakha Well how do you construct `parameter_1` and `parameter_2` in `method()`'s definition? It's unclear to me what you feel would be different between calling a function with the exact same values and just constructing it inline.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I do not think it is necessary to expose the entire class with all its constructors and destructors. Obviously, as they are attributes of `MyClass` class, they have been previously initialised in a way that does not concern the topic. Essentialy, in the `method()` body they are equivalent to `this->parameter_1` and `this->parameter_2`

Comment: @Kaiyakha I am not sure where the disconnect is, but it sounds like you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how member variables and classes work. There's no exposure here. You're describing a situation where `type1_t` and `type2_t` are already parameters to a function, the point is simply to call the overload with more arguments from the nullary function. It doesn't matter where these values come from. If this somehow doesn't work for what you're describing, then that means the two functions don't have overlap and can't reasonably be shared.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I just omitted stuff like `public: type1_t parameter_1; type2_t parameter_2`. I can't really understand why it cannot be obvious.

Comment: @Human-Compiler One more thing is that in case of name conflicts the variable in the parameter list takes priority, so when I pass variables under the same name as attributes, I will either have to use `this` pointer to get access to the attributes or deal with the passed parameters instead. I want to use this feature to have the same code processing either attributes or function parameters depending on the declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need another method which would have exactly the same body, but now I want the parameters to be passed in with the function call:

This can be solved using delegation. Simply call one overload from the other. Example:

```
void MyClass::method(type1_t parameter_1, type2_t parameter_2) {
    parameter_3 = parameter_1 + parameter_2;
}

void MyClass::method() {
    method(parameter_1, parameter_2);
}
```